# How can we convert an arbitrary iterable of iterables into a nested list of lists of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tree

Suppose `obj` has an `__iter__()` method.

We want to write a function which accepts `obj` as input and outputs a nested list of lists of lists .... of lists of strings.

If an object is iterable, and is not a string, we recur.

If an object is a string, we return the string.

If an object is non-iterable, we call the string-class constructor on that object, and return the resulting string.

Unfortunately, there may be self-loops. That is, an objects **iter** method might return an object we have seen previously.

```python
root.__iter__().__next__().__next__().__iter__().__next__().__next__().__iter__().__next__() == root
```

Maybe we should use the `id()` function to check if the object has been seen previously?

Comment: Is the structure also *arbitrarily nested*?

Comment: @MichaelM. I don't think either of those answers addresses the possibility of "self-loops" as described in the OP. Naively recursing on a graph that can contain cycles will generally result in unbounded recursion when such a cycle is present.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable


def collect(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Iterable) and not isinstance(obj, str):
        return list(map(collect, obj))
    else:
        return str(obj)


obj = iter([iter([iter(['a', 2]), 'cd']), iter(['ef', 'gh'])])
print(collect(obj))  # => [[['a', '2'], 'cd'], ['ef', 'gh']]
```

I think that the `id()` check is unnecessary because once an iterator is iterated through, all the elements will be exhausted and there won't be anything else to iterate through. If you need to detect iterators that yield more iterators in an infinite pattern, then I think a foolproof way does not exist, as each new iterator will be a new object with a new ID.

Answer (score 0):

This approach optimistically iterates any non-string `t` and recovers from errors using an exception handler -

```py
def collect(t):
  try:
    if isinstance(t, str):
      return t
    else:
      return list(collect(v) for v in t)
  except TypeError:
    return t
```